# Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта при сбросе combobox

Tags: c#

Есть код, который выводит строки в datagridview при выборе индекса из combobox. Но при сбросе через `comboBox1.SelectedItem = null` выдает ошибку. Почему выдает - понятно, а вот как решать - нет.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{       
    dataGridView1.CurrentCell = null;
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = false;
    for (int c = 0; c < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; c++)
    {
         if(dataGridView1[c, i+1].RowIndex.ToString() == comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString())
         {
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = true;
            break;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Конечно выдаёт, ведь `null.ToString()` никак не выполнится. Проверяйте SelectedItem на null либо (в c# 6.0 и выше) используйте null propagation: `== comboBox1.SelectedItem?.ToString()`

Comment: Вот это выражение `dataGridView1[c, i+1].RowIndex` возвращает индекс строки. Но в цикле и так происходит проход по строкам. То есть это выражение равнозначно следующему: `i+1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну что значит как решать... Самой первой строкой ещё до приведённого кода поставьте проверку на null, вам же оба эти цикла не нужны вообще, если ничего не выбрано, верно?

```
if(comboBox1.SelectedItem == null)
    return;
```

Менее правильный вариант - заменить проверку (в c# 6.0 и выше) используя null propagation:

```
if(dataGridView1[c, i+1].RowIndex.ToString() == comboBox1.SelectedItem?.ToString())
```

(И что-то я не пойму: у вас же и RowIndex и SelectedItem - это наверняка и то и то int, зачем приводить к строкам?)

> Проверка на 0 помогла c ошибкой, но после сброса таблица остается как
>   после фильтрации, а не возвращается к полному списку.

Очень похоже, что вы хотите такую логику:

```
if(comboBox1.SelectedItem == null || dataGridView1[c, i+1].RowIndex.ToString() == comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString())
```

Но также никто не мешает вам определить свою кастомную логику перед выходом:

```
if(comboBox1.SelectedItem == null)
{
    // TODO: Добавить обработку случая, когда нет выделения
    ...
    return;
}
```

Comment: Проверка на 0 помогла c ошибкой, но после сброса таблица остается как после фильтрации, а не возвращается к полному списку. А к строкам пришлось использовать потому что через .Equals он не может найти индекс и выдает пустую таблицу.

Comment: @DanielDashkevich Обновил ответ.

Comment: Работает как надо, спасибо за помощь